# jsPDF Conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to save the data into PDF using jsPdf And i can able to save the HTML data into the PDF But i would like to save the Data which are in the JavaScript file. I'm trying in many ways but only empty PDF's are Downloaded . Is there any way's to Save the JavaScript dynamic data's into PDF . Can some one help me out, Here i attached my code.

```js
 this.print=function(id){
         var id=this.getProcess().id;
          var doc = new jsPDF();
          return _this.processService.printProcess(id).then(function () {
                   _this.snapshots = [];
                   _this.addSnapshot(_this.process);
                   _this.warnCategories();
                   _this.startEditing();
                 doc.save('Meow.pdf');
                 return _this.process;
                 
             });
           
        };
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="pc.printProcess()"  style="width: 90%"> 
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
 </span> <au href="genPDF()">Print </au>
 </button>
```

Here i would like to print the data which are inside **_this.process** this object.

Comment: We have no idea what `printProcess()` or any of the other methods you call inside it do or what `_this.process` is. Looks like all you are doing is creating an empty pdf. You never do anything with `doc`

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl,  printProcess() is just a method,Compiler comes into this method when we click the Print Button(ng-click) . and The Data's i want to print are inside the (_this.process) .

Comment: Is that data not rendered in view? If not you would need to parse it to html. Still not enough known

Comment: yes, It shows. I can able to get the data from the view. Am asking ,Is there any ways to get the data from JS code ?

Comment: Sure if you want to generate html yourself as string by iterating the data, or send to server and use a library there

Comment: Thanks charlietfl  , Another Problem in my application. The Data's which am getting from the Html tags are visible in my Application also , How can i avoid that ?